# LIKE does not work in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using **LIKE** to see if the similar order_id exists or not in my db. When i run the application, i see that this below code doesnt return any value. It is returning only null value.

```
$temp_orders = $this->transaction_model->get_similar_user_temp_transaction($cart_order_id);

function get_similar_user_temp_transaction($order_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('temp_transaction')
        ->like('order_id', $order_id)
        ->get();
    return ($query->num_rows() < 1) ? null : $query->result();
}
```

Kindly check the above code. Help would be appreciated

Comment: it should be `where` not `like` to check id exists or not

Comment: I would like to get similar record if it exists in db

Comment: then also you can use `WHERE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try your code after changing statement order

```
function get_similar_user_temp_transaction($order_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
        ->like('order_id', $order_id)
        ->from('temp_transaction')        
        ->get();
    return ($query->num_rows() < 1) ? null : $query->result();
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to match exact order_id, use `where` instead of `like`

```
function get_similar_user_temp_transaction($order_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
        ->where('order_id', $order_id)
        ->from('temp_transaction')        
        ->get();
    return ($query->num_rows() < 1) ? null : $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Still im getting no records. Say i have a order_id 122. I am trying to match by passing the same order_id. Still same null result

Answer (score 0):

write `like` in `where` cluase

```
 $query = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('temp_transaction')
        ->where("order_id LIKE '%$order_id%'")->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here **SQL like** not work, because like is not working with INT values

You have two options :-

```
1. ->like(CONVERT(order_id, CHAR(16), $order_id)
2. Use ->where(order_id, $order_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to match exact use where clause.

```
//dont need ->select('*') //excluding select gives same equivalent 
//dont need from 

return $this->db->where('order_id', $order_id)->get('temp_transaction')->result();
```